# Iterate into an array of elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I found this problem, it looks simple but I can't find any solution for this. I have an array of elements like below:

```
<input type="text" name="subTotal[]"/>
<input type="text" name="subTotal[]"/>
<input type="text" name="subTotal[]"/>
<input type="text" name="subTotal[]"/>
```

Using jquery, I'd like to count the total from that four subTotal. The count will be triggered when the value of that subTotal is changed. I tried it like below, but it doesn't work:

```
var totalPrice = 0;
$('input[name="subTotal"]').each( function( key, value ) {
    totalPrice += value;
    alert(totalPrice);
});
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a helpful phrase.  Tell us what is happening and what you expect.  You are not binding to any input change event either (at least not in the code you posted).

Comment: Also you need `$(':input')` instead of `$('input')`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, by using `name^=` and parseInt on the value

```
  var totalPrice = 0;
    $('input[name^="subTotal"]').each( function() {
        totalPrice += parseInt(this.value);
        alert(totalPrice);
    });
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/gBudm/

Comment: What has ^ to do in the provided solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name^="subTotal"]').change(function () {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    $('input[name^="subTotal"]').each(function () {
        totalPrice += parseInt(this.value);        
    })
    alert(totalPrice);
});
```

The count will be triggered when the value of that subTotal is changed.
[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/TM4Me/)